# Prove Simply Connected

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, connectedness, fundamental-groups

If $X = U \cup V$ with $U,V$ open and simply connected and $U \cap V$ is path connected, why is $X$ simply connected?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint**: Apply the [van Kampen theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seifert%E2%80%93van_Kampen_theorem).

Answer (score 3):

As **Ayman Hourieh** said, one can use van Kampen's theorem.

But in the present case, it might worth it to prove it by hands to really understand what is going on. Such a direct proof goes as follow (it is kind of the proof of van Kampen's theorem, but in this really simple case) : given a loop $\gamma \colon [0,1] \to X$,

- choose a base point $x_0$ in $U \cap V$,
- pull the cover $\{U,V\}$ back to $[0,1]$ and apply Lebesgue's lemma to get a subdivision $0=i_0 < i_1 <  \dots < i_n = 1$ such that for all $k$, $\gamma \!\!\restriction\!\! [i_k,i_{k+1}]$ has its image entirely either in $U$ or $V$,
- for each portion $\gamma \!\!\restriction\!\! [i_k,i_{k+1}]$ of the loop $\gamma$, construct a loop with base point $x_0$ contained either in $U$ or $V$,
- apply simple connectedness in $U$ and in $V$ to get a homotopy (defined piecewise) from $\gamma$ to the constant loop with value $x_0$.

Comment: This special case is explicitly covered in Munkres book "Topology".

Comment: Do you know what page?

Comment: @LeeMosher Do you know what page in Munkres this problem is? Thanks!

Comment: @Barry Munkres page 369. This is Corollary 59.2

Comment: @user114125 Munkres page 369. This is Corollary 59.2 (sorry for the second comment, but two people asked the same question)